# Shuttle Two Track Secure Mobile MagStripe Reader

Tags: objective-c

How to fetch cvv, account number and expiration date using  " Shuttle Two Track Secure Mobile MagStripe Reader " in iOS?

Comment: Please provide more explanation of what you are trying to do and most importantly show code that you tried and explain what isn't working

Comment: On swiping the card, the data I am receiving is encrypted. I want to decrypt it. It has been encrypted using TDES and AES encryption using DUKPT key management. I am getting this encrypted data in "umSwipe_receivedSwipe", which is a default method given in its SDK.